# Jest Test Error: browserType.launch: setImmediate is not defined. While using Playwright

Tags: javascript, jestjs, playwright

I am getting an error while testing with jest in my Javascript code.

The Error:

FAIL  src/test/testPlaywright.test.jsx (5.779 s)
× Creating a Snapshot of interacting with playwright (149 ms)

● Creating a Snapshot of interacting with playwright

```
browserType.launch: setImmediate is not defined

  4 |     for(const browserType of [chromium, firefox, webkit]){
  5 |         console.log("Testing");
> 6 |         const browser = await browserType.launch({headless: false});
    |                                           ^
  7 |         const page = await browser.newPage();
  8 |         await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(1000000);
  9 |         await page.goto('https://app.wien.gv.at/navigation/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/test/testPlaywright.test.jsx:6:43)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.517 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

The Code:

```
import { chromium, webkit, firefox } from "playwright";

test('Creating a Snapshot of interacting with playwright',async()=>{
    for(const browserType of [chromium, firefox, webkit]){
        console.log("Testing");
        const browser = await browserType.launch({headless: false});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(1000000); 
        await page.goto('https://app.wien.gv.at/navigation/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });

        await page.click("(//mat-icon[text()='keyboard_arrow_down'])[1]")
        await page.click("#mat-select-0")
        await page.click('//span[@class="mat-option-text"][contains(.,"Veranstaltungszentrum")]')
        await page.click("//mat-icon[text()='keyboard_arrow_up']")
        
        await page.click("(//mat-icon[text()='keyboard_arrow_down'])[2]")
        await page.click("#mat-select-3")
        await page.click('//span[@class="mat-option-text"][contains(.,"Kapelle Krankenhaus Hietzing")]')

        await page.waitForTimeout(2000);

        await page.screenshot({path:'image-'+browserType.name()+'.png'});
        
        await browser.close();
    }
})
```

Comment: related: `import {setImmediate} from 'timers'` https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/8558

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Problem is the setImmediate function.

I just added the polyfill.js in my test class : import 'core-js';
after that setImmediate was defined again and works now as intended.

Comment: thanks this worked for me, I added `core-js` to my `setupFiles` array in `jest.config.js`

Comment: Strangely enough, although I swear it used to be supported, latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and even edge no longer support setImmediate (and it can be easily polyfilled with setTimeout(() => func(), 0) so maybe it wasn't worth it to maintain.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate

Answer (score 8):

As of Jest 28 you can set the `testEnvironment` on a per-file basis. For example, your main `jest.config.js` can have

```
testEnvironment: 'jsdom'
```

but then in an individual file that runs in the Node environment you can put this at the top:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */
```

which will allow `setImmediate()` and other Node-specific things to work.

Comment: wow you could do this!!!

Answer (score 3):

another way to solve it is installing `setimmediate`
with `npm install -D setimmediate` and import it **before** cloudinary

it must look like this

```
import 'setimmediate';
import cloudinary from 'cloudinary';
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked well for me, in *`react-native`* environment, was the following

1. run on the terminal:

```bash
yarn add -D core-js
```

2. and add inside of the `jest.config.js` file, or the config file configured on the jest parameter ***setupFiles*** the following *`import`*

```
import 'core-js';
```

Comment: This helped me massively after 24hrs of banging my head against the wall. I am rendering the FAB component from react-native-paper and it breaks my jest testing-library/react-native tests with `Error: Uncaught [ReferenceError: setImmediate is not defined]`. I did `npm install core-js`, created a core-js.js file with `import coreJs from 'core-js'; export default coreJs;` in it, and have `setupFiles: ['./core-js.js']` in my `jest.config.js` file

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your jest.config.js contains

> testEnvironment: 'jsdom'

you can try remove this setting or

> testEnvironment: 'node'

I hope you have good luck.

Comment: This won't work when testing UI, there should be another solution or bug fix

Comment: +1 As much as this isn't a solution, it helped my understand where the problem is coming from. Unfortunately, the test that is causing this doesn't even test the UI, so I'm not sure why jsdom would be causing trouble.

Answer (score 0):

i had a case, updating to Jest27 where we used 'setImmediate' to resolve promises as a test helper.

we *require* `testEnvironment: 'jsdom'` for our browser related tests and test environment.

to give credit, most of my trial, error and information came from here:
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/8558

however, TLDR;

`import {setImmediate} from 'timers';`
in our case to reference it properly from module.

this was the *only* fix from all advice that worked. simply import `setImmediate` where we used it and thereby avoid the previous unintentional exposure directly from node in a jsdom env jest 26.x and below.

this is similar to another answer above but in my case I didn't have to install an additional explicit npm package to use it.

Answer (score 0):

For React testing using jest assigning the setTimeout() to global setImmediate() will fix it for you, you may need **ts-ignore** to disable checking if you are using typescript

```
// @ts-ignore
window.setImmediate = window.setTimeout
```